# Using mod_rewrite to redirect old urls with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm redeveloping a website using the codeigniter framework.

When we go live, we want to ensure a few of the old URLs will be redirected to the appropriate pages on the new site.

So I put what I thought would be the correct rules into the existing htaccess file, above the other rules that CodeIgniter applies.

However, they are not taking affect. Can anyone suggest what I'm missing here?

```
# pickup links pointing to the old site structure
RewriteRule ^(faq|contact)\.php$ /info/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^registration\.php$ /register/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^update_details\.php$ /change/ [R=301]

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^_system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
# Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^myapp.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# This snippet re-routes everything through index.php, unless
# it's being sent to resources
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a [L]ast flag to your R=301 flag => [L,R=301] that makes sure no other rules are applied, and, just to be sure, try to redirect to a complete URL and, to be even more sure you haven't deleted anything, add RewriteEngine On to the top and set the RewriteBase.

Make your first rows look like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(faq|contact)\.php$ http://www.YOURDOMAIN.XYZ/info/ [L,R=301]
```

and check if the URL in your browser changes when you call for instance the faq page.